# Squid/Kerberos authentication with only Linux

Tags: linux, squid, kerberos, proxy-authentication

I would like to know if it possible to let a Windows Xp machine authenticate to Squid (Linux) using Kerberos without the need of an Active Directory domain.

I only want to create a Kerberos ticket on the client side, which should give the client access to squid (using I.E.).

I only found tutorials about configuring A.D./Squid, not an environment with only Linux servers.

Thanks

Update:

The kerberos setup is correctly done, the proxy and client can get tickets.

As for the browser (FF/IE), I get:

```
ERROR
Cache Access Denied

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://www.google.com/

The following error was encountered:

    * Cache Access Denied. 

Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request:

    http://www.google.com/

from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.
```

In kerberos, I get:

```
squid_kerb_auth: Got 'YR ElRNTVMTUABBAABAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFASgDAAAADw==' from squid (length: 59).
squid_kerb_auth: parseNegTokenInit failed with rc=101
squid_kerb_auth: received type 1 NTLM token
```

This message is strange, as I didn't configure NTLM. It looks like the browser uses the wrong authentication methode.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed familiar and Google searching brought me [back to ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/129854/authenticating-windows-7-against-mit-kerberos-5).  Long story short, Micros*** extends Kerberos in a way that makes client authentication with alternative Kerberos implementations (e.g. MIT or Heimdal) not easily accomplished.  This is why projects like [pGina](http://www.pgina.org/index.php/Main_Page) were created.  That might be primarily for LDAP auth, but the cause will lead to you needing a similar result, namely coding your own custom GINA DLL to handle that kind of auth.  If you find one that handles Kerberos, please let us know!  I would be super-excited to use it and find out.

Comment: In the Windows side, I make a ticket using the Network Identity Manager (this works). When I access the internet using the gateway I get:

The following error was encountered:
    * Cache Access Denied. 
Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request:
    http://www.google.be
from this cache until you have authenticated yourself. 

I did not yet configure squid in the proxyserver as service. Can someone help me?

So my setup:
*Windows XP client (connection with Kerberos server using Network Identity Manager OK)
*Linux Kerberos Server
*Linux Squid Server (connection with Kerberos server OK)

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is.  I thought you wanted to have a computer **login** with credentials from a Linux Kerberos box.  Your problem is that the important stuff is after the line `squid_kerb_auth: received type 1 NTLM token`.  You might want to post that here.  That being said, the line after that is usually self-explanatory.  Here is one example: `2010/08/29 11:09:15| squid_kerb_auth: parseNegTokenInit failed with rc=101
2010/08/29 11:09:15| squid_kerb_auth: received type 1 NTLM token
2010/08/29 11:09:15| authenticateNegotiateAuthenticateUser: need to
challenge client 'received'!`